# Admob “The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.ads.AdView” Android XML Issue

Tags: android, xml, sdk, admob

Im trying to get the google admob sdk integrated to display ads in an android application writen in xml. Yes I have already made sure that admob jar is checked in order and export under build path!

I realize there are other open questions but none of the answers solved my issue! Im getting no errors, my project.properties is set to target 19 and my manifest has this:

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

and I will post my entire main layout page
Please help me guys!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text_mainmenu"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="[MYIDHERE]"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you getting log showing the ads are being requested, received? Post your logcat

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. There are some issues with the Graphical Layout when you are rendering layouts in Eclipse for Android-19 (KitKat). You cannot change items in the Properties window for example.

Switching to Android-18 in Graphical Layout (green Android top-right) solved the problem for me.